# How to separate business classes and auxiliary traits in Cake Pattern?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

The [Cake Pattern](http://www.jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di.html) looks as follows:

```
trait UserRepositoryComponent {  
  val userRepository: UserRepository  
  class UserRepository {...}
}

trait UserServiceComponent {this: UserRepositoryComponent =>   
  val userService: UserService    
  class UserService {...}  
}
```

The classes `UserService` and `UserRepository` are real business classes. We can use them with and without the Cake pattern.

The traits `UserServiceComponent` and `UserRepositoryComponent`, on the contrary, are just auxiliary boilerplate code rather than real business components. We need them just to implement the pattern.

Given that, I would not like `UserService` and `UserRepository` to be inner classes of `UserServiceComponent` and `UserRepositoryComponent`. Does it make sense? Can I implement them not as inner classes?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t **need** to wrap your implementation classes, e.g. you could write something like that:

```
trait UserRepository { ... }
trait UserService { this: UserRepository => ... }
```

But creating you components would need to instantiate a single object containing all your components at once:

```
new UserRepositoryImpl with UserServiceImpl
```

So, methods from `UserRepository` and `UserService` would be mixed in a single instance, which is not necessarily what you want (and which would cause problems if your components define methods with the same name).

Thus, wrapping your components in “boilerplate” traits creates useful namespaces.